# Adding custom drop-down in jQuery Datatable broke down the sorting action

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to add the custom dropdown search in jQuery datatable. And this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3L4tv7uy/2/) is what I have achieved so far. I am able to filter the column on change of dropdown option.

Now, I have almost achieved 90% of my goal. But this error is stopping me reaching to 100%. This implementation caused the sorting buttons to move below down to the search box. And whenever I am click on search box, it sorts the respective column first.

[image]

This is my code:

```
/* Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var max = parseInt($('#cars').children("option:selected").val(), 10 );
        var age = parseFloat( data[3] ) || 0; // use data for the age column

        if (isNaN( max ) || age <= max )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example thead th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );

    table.column(3).every( function () {

        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select id="cars"><option value=""></option><option value="20">20</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="50">50</option></select>')
          .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())

    });

    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#cars').change( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );
} );
```

Kindly let me know how I should remove the sorting option from the search box line and move the sorting option back to the table header row. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version of your code with some changes.

The end-result is a table which looks like this:

[image]

The HTML is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/sorting/intl.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tabs.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.6/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">

  <style>
    thead input {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 3px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>

            [data removed for brevity!]

            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var dropdown = '<select id="age_select">' +
      '<option value="-1">Select Age</option>' +
      '<option value="49">< 50 Years</option>' +
      '<option value="50">>= 50 Years</option>';

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var filter = parseInt( $('#age_select').val(), 10 );
    var age = parseFloat( data[3] ) || 0; // use data for the age column
    if ( filter == -1) {
      return true;
    }
    if ( ( filter >= 50 && age >= filter ) ||
         ( filter < 50 && age <= filter ) ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
);

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each header cell
    $('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#example thead' );
    $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
        if (i != 3) { // column 4 (index 3) is the 'Age' column
          // the input fields:
          var title = $(this).text();
          $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '"/>' );

          $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
              if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                table.column(i).search( this.value ).draw();
              }
          } );
        } else {
          // the 'Age' column drop-down field:
          $(this).html( dropdown );
          $( 'select', this ).on( 'change', function () {
            // delegate to the external search function (see above):
            table.draw();
          } );
        }

    } );

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true
    } );

} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Points to Note:**

1) I use `fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css` in the above - it's left over from another demo - I don't think it's actually relevant for you - you can probably remove it.

2) There is hard-coding for the "greater/less than 50" logic. I'm sure there are ways to improve that - but for this demo, I hope that's OK.

3) I removed most of the HTML test data, to keep the code listing short.

Comment: Thanks your solution worked. And also, I didn't need any new external js files.Your code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply stop the script to sort by stopPropagation.

Just place this code in your script:

```
  $('input').click(function(e) {


      e.stopPropagation();

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>jQuery320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>jQuery170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>jQuery86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>jQuery433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>jQuery162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>jQuery372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>jQuery137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>jQuery327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>jQuery205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>jQuery103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>jQuery90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>jQuery342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>jQuery470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>jQuery313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>jQuery385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>jQuery198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>jQuery725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>jQuery237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>jQuery132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>2012/09/26</td>
      <td>jQuery217,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
      <td>Development Lead</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2011/09/03</td>
      <td>jQuery345,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yuri Berry</td>
      <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>2009/06/25</td>
      <td>jQuery675,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caesar Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2011/12/12</td>
      <td>jQuery106,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doris Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2010/09/20</td>
      <td>jQuery85,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>jQuery1,200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>2010/12/22</td>
      <td>jQuery92,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2010/11/14</td>
      <td>jQuery357,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>jQuery206,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fiona Green</td>
      <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>2010/03/11</td>
      <td>jQuery850,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shou Itou</td>
      <td>Regional Marketing</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>2011/08/14</td>
      <td>jQuery163,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michelle House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2011/06/02</td>
      <td>jQuery95,400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suki Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>2009/10/22</td>
      <td>jQuery114,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/05/07</td>
      <td>jQuery145,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
      <td>Team Leader</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2008/10/26</td>
      <td>jQuery235,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Martena Mccray</td>
      <td>Post-Sales support</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/03/09</td>
      <td>jQuery324,050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unity Butler</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/12/09</td>
      <td>jQuery85,675</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/12/16</td>
      <td>jQuery164,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
      <td>Secretary</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2010/02/12</td>
      <td>jQuery109,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>2009/02/14</td>
      <td>jQuery452,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2008/12/11</td>
      <td>jQuery136,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>2008/09/26</td>
      <td>jQuery645,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Olivia Liang</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2011/02/03</td>
      <td>jQuery234,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruno Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>2011/05/03</td>
      <td>jQuery163,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2009/08/19</td>
      <td>jQuery139,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thor Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2013/08/11</td>
      <td>jQuery98,540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finn Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/07/07</td>
      <td>jQuery87,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2012/04/09</td>
      <td>jQuery138,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>jQuery125,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>2012/06/01</td>
      <td>jQuery115,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
      <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2013/02/01</td>
      <td>jQuery75,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cara Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/12/06</td>
      <td>jQuery145,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione Butler</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2011/03/21</td>
      <td>jQuery356,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lael Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2009/02/27</td>
      <td>jQuery103,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2010/07/14</td>
      <td>jQuery86,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shad Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/11/13</td>
      <td>jQuery183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>2011/06/27</td>
      <td>jQuery183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>jQuery112,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var max = parseInt(jQuery('#age_select').children("option:selected").val(), 10);
    var age = parseInt(data[3]) || 0; // use data for the call_duration column
    var selected_index = jQuery('#age_select').prop('selectedIndex');
    if ((selected_index == 1) && (isNaN(max) || age < max)) {
      return true;
    } else if ((selected_index == 2) && (isNaN(max) || age >= max)) {
      return true;
    } else if (isNaN(max)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
);
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#example thead');

  jQuery('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function() {
    var title = jQuery(this).text();
      jQuery(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width: 100%"/>');
  });

  // DataTable
  var table = jQuery('#example').DataTable();

  table.columns().every(function() {
    var that = this;
    jQuery('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function() {

 
      if (that.search() !== this.value) {
   
  
   
   
        that.search(this.value).draw();
      }
    });
  });

  table.column(3).every(function() {
    var column = this;
    var dropdown = '<select id="age_select">' +
      '<option value="">Select Age</option>' +
      '<option value="50">< 50 Years.</option>' +
      '<option value="50">>= 50 Years</option>'
    var select = jQuery(dropdown).appendTo(jQuery(column.header()).empty());
  });
  
  $('input').click(function(e) {
  

   e.stopPropagation();
  
  });
  
  
  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just added working code snippet as well.  This will not automatically sort by clicking on search fields.  Search fields will do searching only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want sort action buttons in search input row. I want sort action buttons in the table header colum row.

Comment: Your welcome,  Right For that andrewJames has already given the answer.